# Add a config file for a new configuration in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-4.0

I have a web app with the default Web.Config file which has 2 "child" (or how do you call them?) config files: Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.Config.

But I'll need to deploy to QA and staging environments, each of which have separate SQLServer instances which require different connections strings. I'll need separate configurations for these, so I've added some configurations in Build > Configuration Manager.

**QUESTION**: how do I add another "child" config file for each new configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the config file, then chose "Add Config Transforms."